# GeoNode 2.6.x Logout Issue

Tags: geoserver, geonode

I'm configuring a GIS Portal with GeoNode 2.6.x running on Windows 7 but I'm now confusing with an error. When I try to logout the `admin` account, the error is shown and I don't know what's wrong:

```
KeyError at /account/logout/
'LOGOUT_ENDPOINT'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost/account/logout/
Django Version: 1.8.17
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 'LOGOUT_ENDPOINT'
Exception Location: C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\geonode\base\models.py in do_logout, line 1026
Python Executable:  C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\Apache2\bin\Apache.exe
Python Version: 2.7.8
Python Path:    
['C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\geonode\\Lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\DLLs',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\lib',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\lib\\plat-win',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\Apache2\\bin',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\Python27\\Lib',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\Python27\\DLLs',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\geonode-2.6.x\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\GeoNode-2.6.x\\Apache2']

Traceback:
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\account\views.py" in post
  375.             auth.logout(self.request)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py" in logout
  130.     user_logged_out.send(sender=user.__class__, request=request, user=user)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py" in send
  189.             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
File "C:\GeoNode-2.6.x\geonode-2.6.x\geonode\base\models.py" in do_logout
  1026.                                             settings.OGC_SERVER['default']['LOGOUT_ENDPOINT'],
```

I checked several sites with different solutions and those didn't fix with my problem. I also found that the authentication set on GeoServer OAuth2 has some problems and I'm not sure whether it is related (cannot authorize user and get `Error: invalid_request Missing client_id parameter.` error from `http://localhost/o/authorize/`). The token endpoint checking also returns `{"error": "invalid_request"}`.

How can I solve this...??

Comment: I'd suggest asking on the GeoNode mailing list if you don't get an answer here - https://lists.osgeo.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/geonode-users

Comment: you can use [cartoview installer](https://cartoview.net/) it installs geonode, and remove cartoview if you don't it.